# Why close questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm curious (and a little aggravated) as to why you would close a users question as too "localized"?  Here I am, looking to solve the same problem and the answer is closed.  Why not let user questions be addressed?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/112601/why-access-is-denied-to-windows-users-when-saving-files-in-a-dir-shared-with-sam

Comment: Feel free to ask a question about the same problem, just remember to include all error messages, and specifications.

Answer (score 3):

That question is closed because it's impossible to answer without any new information from the poster, so it's basically abandoned. The question in its current state isn't really helping anybody, so it's closed.

Feel free to just ask a new one!

Comment: With majority of bugs done away with, the only ones remain are localized ones. What to do at such times? We or rather the OP can add new info if the question is related or the original asker can.

Comment: sure, but most people don't do that, they just tend to ask a new question. If someone wants to take over a closed question and start improving it so we can reopen it then that's fine too.

Comment: you need rep for that, right?

Comment: No, you don't need reputation to submit improvements to questions or answers, though for most people it's easier to just post their own question than take over someone else's.

Comment: We could append it to the closed question or would that be too cumbersome?

Comment: I would just rewrite it to make sense.